# Check List if data exists then input value again

Tags: java, list, arraylist

**My main goal is to identify if a number enters is not duplicated in the list, else user needs to update a new number. The system will keep asking user to enter non duplicate numbers.**

I am currently struggling to get the logic in order to check if my List contains a duplicate ID. If someone inputs a duplicate ID, then he will be prompted to re-enter a new number. The new number will be checked again until the system satisfies with no duplicate element. The following function returns an integer, which will be added to the List of type Course in the main method.

The following is the snippet of my function:

```
public static int ifExist(List<Course> courselist, Iterator<Course> itr,  int personid) {
        
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean found = false;
        boolean flag = false;
        int personid2 = personid;
        String value = null;
        
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Course courseItr = itr.next();
                if(courseItr.getPersonID() == personid) {
                    found = true;
                    flag = true;
                    
                    while(found == true) {
                        System.out.print("No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: ");
                        do {
                            // must be a digit from 1 - 10,000
                            String digit = "\\d{1,10000}";
                            value = input.nextLine();
                            flag = value.matches(digit);
                            if (!flag) System.out.print("Please a number only!: ");
                        } while (!flag);
                        personid2 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        
                        if(personid2 != courseItr.getPersonID()) {
                            found= false;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        return personid2;
        
    }
```

The output while executing the Course program can be shown below. Note that entering no 1 means adding a course list.

```
Please select your choice: 1

Enter the person ID: 1
Enter the person name: Alysa
Enter the title of the course: Maths
Enter the year of joining: 2021
Enter the fee of the course: 20.50
New Course has successfully been added.

Please select your choice: 1

Enter the person ID: 1
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 1
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 1
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 1
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 2
Enter the person name: Maria
Enter the title of the course: Biology
Enter the year of joining: 2021
Enter the fee of the course: 25.99
New Course has successfully been added.

Please select your choice: 1

Enter the person ID: 2
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 2
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 2
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 2
No duplicate number is accepted. Please enter another number: 1
Enter the person name: Peter
Enter the title of the course: Chemistry
Enter the year of joining: 2021
Enter the fee of the course: 50.50
New Course has successfully been added.
```

As shown in the above, it shows that my ifExist method is not working (trying to get the logic right). The two persons have the same ID, such 1.

When I tried to display the Course List

```
Please select your choice: 3
Person ID: 1, Name: Alysa, Title: Maths, Year: 2021, Fee: $20.5.
Person ID: 2, Name: Maria, Title: Biology, Year: 2021, Fee: $25.99.
Person ID: 1, Name: Peter, Title: Chemistry, Year: 2021, Fee: $50.5.
```

I have googled it, but it seems that I either have to use Set to remove any duplicates or use equals/hashcode(). Nevertheless, I would be highly appreciated if any experienced java programmer to help clarify or provide any idea on how to resolve this problem.

**NEWLY ADDED METHOD**

```
public static void addCourse(List<Course> courselist, Course course) {
        //check if the id is the same or not
        
        ListIterator<Course> itr = courselist.listIterator();
        
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            int personid, year;
            String author, title;
            double fee;
                
            System.out.print("\nEnter the person ID: ");
            personid = input.nextInt();
            personid = ifExist(booklist, itr, personid);
            course.setPersonDd(personid);

...
...
...
courselist.add(new Course(personid, author, title, year, fee));
            System.out.println("New Course has successfully been added.");

} catch {
}
}
```

Thank you. Look forward to hearing from fellow developers.

Regards,
Simone11

Comment: i think the issue not on those method it about your list 
after you get the personID are and get the other data are you sure you add that course object to the same exact list

try to add break point to your method then use the debug mode of your ide it will help you

Comment: Can you also include the method that calls `ifExist`?

Comment: Yes. I have a addCourse method in main method. This method will add info. If I enter an ID of type primitive int. Its value is passed to the ifExist method, then returns an integer. This integer will be set onto my Course object as course.setPersonID(return integer). Then I add object Course to the List, courselist.add(new Course(info, etc));

Comment: @TimMoore you mean a recursive function? I did, but did not work. I think my logic is not there yet. Once the previous ID and new ID are compared, the newID is expected to return. However, if I enter a new number, the current system will repeat the previous previous number with the newest number.

Comment: No, I didn’t mean that. I wanted to see the code that calls the method above. The bug has partly to do with the way that it’s used.

Comment: @TimMoore done updating my question. I use a menu system. I constructed my List<Course> coursellist = new ArrayList<Course>(); and Course course = new Course(); in the main method. So addCourse is a method in the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first method**

The problem lies in the iterator. When the user inputs `1` after `2`, the iterator has already gone through the Course with the ID `1`, so it is unable to detect duplicate IDs. Hence, every time the user inputs a new number, you must restart the iteration.

The `List<Course> courselist` parameter is unused.

With that said, this program is not logically optimized. The `ifExists(,)` method should solely work on searching for courses with the same ID. As for handling user input, it should be done completely outside of the method.

Here is an example of the `ifExists(,)` method

```java
public static boolean ifExists(int id, Iterator<Course> iterator){
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Course next = iterator.next();
        if (next.id == id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in the main method, your messages to the user are based on the value returned by this method. Here is an example:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int id = scanner.nextInt();
while (ifExists(id)) {
    System.out.println("Duplicated ID! Please try another number.");
    id = scanner.nextInt();
} // If ifExists(id) returns false, continue to the code below to enter personal details
```

**Regarding your second method**

Use `HashSet` instead of `List` or `Iterator`. You can directly call `HashSet.contains(Obj)` to check whether a `Course` already exists in the collection, without looping through the items. Even though `List` also has this method, it loops through all the items, which is similar to what you are doing.

This is because `HashSet` orders items by their hash code instead of the order of being added, but `List` doesn't. So when you call the `contains` method, it looks for entry no. (insert hash code).

Comment: I highly appreciate your 2 pieces of code. I already following the algorithms. But it does not work at all.  Inputted 1 twice and the problem continues entering the person name instead of validating that the same ID has occurred.

I have not used HashSet yet because I would prefer to solve this issue first.

Comment: @guyonstuckoverflow I have updated some minor mistakes on my code.
1. `scanner.nextInt()` instead of `next()`
2. I should have ended the iteration right when a duplicate is found, instead of waiting through the entire iteration.

Aside from the issues above, the code should work completely fine. Maybe you have bugs at other places that are not shown in the question

Comment: thank you for this. It does not work still. I am going to change my List to Set if that works in Course class to see if that eliminates the issue

Comment: @guyonstuckoverflow If it's still the same bug, you can try to debug yourself. Alternatively, you can append your current code to the question and let others see. If it's another bug, you should start a new question, but make sure you follow the code of conducts.

Comment: Thankfully I have finally solved the issue. I am using the Set interface of the LinkedHashSet class. I created a method that returns true if my set does not contain a duplicated ID and a new id is added in my set, if duplicated it will keep iterating until it becomes false. So I override two methods such as equals and hashcode() which only restricts duplicate IDs in my course class. I referred to your second snippet of code and created my own logic. Thank you